# Speed of a space ship

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, doppler-effect

> You are on the International Space Station when a ship illuminated with a source of sodium (an intense yellow light wavelength 588.9950 and 589.5924 $nm$) comes close. In the station you have a device that can resolve two very close wavelengths when the difference between them is $\Delta\lambda<0.60 nm$. If you can resolve the sodium doublet, how fast is the ship travelling relative to you?

My idea is to use the relativistic Doppler effect

$f_{observed}=f_{source}\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{v}{c}}{1-\frac{v}{c}}}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{c}{\lambda_o}=\frac{c}{\lambda_s}\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{v}{c}}{1-\frac{v}{c}}}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda_o=\lambda_s\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{v}{c}}{1+\frac{v}{c}}}=\lambda_s\sqrt{\frac{c-v}{c+v}}$

where $v$ is the relative velocity between the two systems (ISS and ship). Then

$\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_o}{\lambda_s}}=\frac{c-v}{c+v}$ $\Rightarrow$ $v=\frac{c-c\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_o}{\lambda_s}}}{1+\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_o}{\lambda_s}}}$

Is this correct?

And, $\lambda_o=0.60 nm$ and $\lambda_s=589.5924-588.9950 nm$?

Comment: So what answer do you get?

Comment: Is the sodium light emitted by the space ship or by the ISS?

Comment: @sammygerbil Is emitted by the ship, but my question is if the values of $\lambda_o$ and $\lambda_s$ are corrects or not.